# Yii не видит таблицу

Tags: php, yii

Делаю поиск по бд выдает ошибку, а таблица сама есть

```
CDbException
The table "users" for active record class "Users" cannot be found in the database.

    /var/www/site/yii/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(2310)
```

Ругается именно на

```
public function __construct($model)
{
    $this->_model=$model;

    $tableName=$model->tableName();
    if(($table=$model->getDbConnection()->getSchema()->getTable($tableName))===null)
        throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','The table "{table}" for active record class "{class}" cannot be found in the database.',
            array('{class}'=>get_class($model),'{table}'=>$tableName)));
    if($table->primaryKey===null)
    {
        $table->primaryKey=$model->primaryKey();
        if(is_string($table->primaryKey) && isset($table->columns[$table->primaryKey]))
            $table->columns[$table->primaryKey]->isPrimaryKey=true;
        elseif(is_array($table->primaryKey))
        {
            foreach($table->primaryKey as $name)
            {
                if(isset($table->columns[$name]))
                    $table->columns[$name]->isPrimaryKey=true;
            }
        }
    }
    $this->tableSchema=$table;
    $this->columns=$table->columns;

    foreach($table->columns as $name=>$column)
    {
        if(!$column->isPrimaryKey && $column->defaultValue!==null)
            $this->attributeDefaults[$name]=$column->defaultValue;
    }

    foreach($model->relations() as $name=>$config)
    {
        $this->addRelation($name,$config);
    }
}
```

main.php

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db',
    'emulatePrepare' => true,
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
),
```

помогите решить проблему

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что бросается в глаза, у вас в конфигурационном файле указан [префикс](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#tablePrefix-detail) для всех таблиц в БД:

```php
'db' => array(
    'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_',
),
```

убедитесь, что он присутствует в названии соответствующей таблицы или удалите это свойство, если не используете префиксы.

Comment: у меня все таблицы tbl_users итд такой префикс точно есть

Comment: @reddyk, что у вас прописано в методе `tableName()` в модели `Users`?

Comment: public function tableName()
 {
  return 'users';
 }

Comment: @reddyk, замените в `return` название таблицы на `'{{users}}'` и попробуйте снова.

Comment: все так же та же ошибка выходит